# Distribution of the value of a portfolio

Tags: portfolio, distribution

Suppose there are k different stocks in a stock market. All of their prices are independent from each other. One year from now the price of the i-th stock will be $X_i^2$, where $X_i \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)  $
What is the distribution of the value of a portfolio after a year if I buy a $1 piece from each stock?

Will it be simple the Chi-squared distribution with parameter k?

Comment: You more or less wrote down the definition of the Chi-squared distribution ... a weird example of a stock-market .. right? But thinking about variance (squared returns) it makes sense..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its Chi-Square distribution ($k=$ number of portfolio assets): http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_distribution#Definition

Comment: What do you mean by setting $k=1$?

Comment: @Hansen Its when you have a variable $k$, it can have a value $1$.

Comment: $k$ is the number of stocks in the portfolio and can take on any natural number. It is just a bit strange that you set $k=1$. Are you trying to give an example for when $k=1$ as opposed to, say, $k=217$?

Comment: @Hansen Yes sry, I misread from the question $X_1^2$, but I suppose its $X_i^2$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It is a simple transformation of the product of the Gaussians from the Cartesian to the hyper-spherical coordinate.